# Collection of R objects in one

Tags: r, object

I am newbie of R and have this very basic doubt: Can we have any other means of creating one object which is the collection of multiple objects, such as matrix, data frame and vector? As per my knowledge it can only be done using list object.

Say I have matrix x,

```
x <- matrix(1:12,nrow=4)
y <- data.frame(x)
z <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Generation of list my_list,

```
my_list <- list(x, y, z)
```

But if there is some other way than above one, I would like to know that.

Comment: You could also use an [environment](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few other ways of returning data

1. **Lists** (for completeness)

   ```
   group1 = list(x, y, z)
   ```
2. **Environments**

   ```
   group2 = new.env()
   group2$x = x
   group2$y = y
   group2$z = z
   ls(envir=group2)
   ```
3. **S4 objects**

   ```
   setClass("group3",
            representation(
              x = "matrix",
              y = "data.frame",
              z = "character"
        )
   )
   s4 = new("group3", x=x, y=y, z=z)
   ```
4. **Reference objects**

   ```
   group4 = setRefClass("group4",
               fields = list(x = "matrix",
                             y = "data.frame",
                             z = "character"))
   group4$new(x=x, y=y, z=z)
   ```
5. **Function closures**

   ```
   group5 = function(x, y, z) function() return(list(x, y, z))
   g5 = group5(x, y, y)
   g5()
   ```

The last example (function closures) is trying to highlight that there a lots of ways to return your data, but you should think carefully about what you want to do with the returned object. For example, using an S4 object to return your example data set is overkill. But bioconductor uses S4 objects (combined with environments) to group together complex data sets from microarray experiments.

Comment: I’m not sure how good the “function closure” example is since it returns a `list` – we’re back to (square) one. The example doesn’t make it clear that it’s the *closure itself* which holds the objects in the first place, and we don’t need to return them as a list.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, the function closure isn't a great example, but it was meant to show you should carefully think what you want to do with the data. BTW, g5 is a (useless?) `function` not a `list`

Comment: I’m aware of that – but its value is a list, which is the potentially confusing part. Unfortunately a more meaningful example is by necessity more complex.

Comment: Do you think FCs should be drop it from the answer? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Definitely not, closures are in a way the most interesting part of the answer (after all, that’s where object orientation came from originally). You can even leave the example as-is, together with your explanation and the comments it should hopefully be clear enough.